# python class; which method for calculating mean, adding a new instance, adding a list of instances

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods, attributes, instance

I have a Python class of grades:

```
class Grades:
    def __init__(self, student, grade):
        self.name = student
        self.grade = grade
```

How do I create a method that can calculate the mean of all grades? Should it be a class/static/instance method?

Also what is the best way to write a method to add a list of instances?

Finally which method could be written to delete all existing data (all instances)?

Thank you!